# 3 stars when defeating the pigmobile

Tags: angry-birds-space

I've beaten the pig on Pig Bang level 1-30 with two or three birds and got 73760 as my highest score, which is enough for two stars.  I'm guessing the 3-stars score is around 75k.  The problem is that there's not much in the way of points in this level, and I don't think I can beat it with just one bird.  I'm stumped as to how I can 3-star this, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Un?)fortunately, Angry Birds is pretty much [non-deterministic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44595/is-angry-birds-deterministic) for touchscreen devices, so sometimes you just have to keep trying and hope you get lucky. This is especially true for this level.

The general idea here is to create a chain reaction where one rock would burst the bubbles of the other ones. Both vegetables and rocks can burst bubbles, but only rocks can damage the vehicle. It takes around 4 rock impacts to destroy the pigmobile. Since gravity is at work here, aiming higher helps.

Here are two not-very-helpful screenshots that'll hopefully illustrate the idea. And yes, getting 76k requires you to only use the first bird.

[image]

[image]